# Is there a way to git cherry-pick ONTO another branch?

Tags: git, github

I work on projects with a more mercurial-like workflow where you put a single commit up for review and land it by itself. Github requires that you have a branch for this. So there is always this redundant one-branch-per-one-commit dance you have to do.

So if I'm working on a set of changes that are related but not dependent, I prefer to work with them down a single branch while waiting for reviews and landing. e.g.

```
commit1 <--HEAD
commit2
commit3
commit4 <--master
```

but I'll have to land these as

```
commit1 <--commit-one-branch
commit4 <--master

commit2 <--commit-two-branch
commit4 <--master
```

etc...

The long boring process would be to create a branch with commits one through three and then

```
git checkout -b worktree
git checkout -b commit-one-branch master
git cherry-pick commit-one
git push myrepo commit-one-branch
git checkout worktree
```

etc... And clearly this gets even uglier if you have to amend changes at any point in time.

What I really want is `git publish <commit> <parent> --branch <branch-name>` or something creates a new branch starting at `<parent>` and `cherry-pick`s `<commit>` on top and creates the branch for you so you can just push it.

I could write this easily enough, but I figure somebody else has to have thought about this before me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> but I figure somebody else has to have thought about this before me.

I doubt it, because that is not how Git is used, and not how [pull-requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/)/[merge-requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) are done.

You create only one branch and push commits (in your case, one commit if you really want) to the remote PR branch, triggering a PR/MR review.

Once the review is completed and the commit is merged to the target branch (say master), you can rebase your local PR/MR branch on top of master and resume working on it.

Answer (score 0):

To burst a branch into single-commit branches off the upstream base for parallel pull requests,

```
for commit in `git rev-list @{u}..`; do
      short=$(git rev-parse --short $commit) # to make the list readable
      branchable_subject=`git log -1 --pretty=%s $short | tr -sc A-Za-z0-9 .`
      echo git branch -f $branchable_subject $short
      echo git rebase --onto @{u} $short^ $branchable_subject
done  # |sh
```